business central is showing an empty page after login in drools business central workbench 7.74
I use kubernetes to deploy drools Business Central and expose port 8080, but when I enter username and password and log in, it appears a empty screen, and I cannot log in to the console.
I use this yaml file for deploy
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: business-central-pod
  labels:
    app: business-central
spec:
  containers:
    - name: business-central-workbench
      image: quay.io/kiegroup/business-central-workbench:7.74.1.Final
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: business-central-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: business-central
  ports:
    - name: wildfly
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
      nodePort: 30808

After the pod is running, I use this command to register an account:
kubectl exec -it business-central-pod -- ./add-user.sh -a --user admin --password admin --role admin

I tried checking the log, but there was no error message.
The latest log file contains the following messages:
05:06:48,963 INFO  [org.jboss.errai.bus.server.cluster.noop.NoopClusteringProvider] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) clustering support not configured.
05:06:48,967 INFO  [org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.bootstrap.OrderedBootstrap] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) starting errai bus ...
05:06:48,968 INFO  [org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.bootstrap.DefaultComponents] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) using dispatcher implementation: org.jboss.errai.bus.server.SimpleDispatcher
05:06:48,971 INFO  [org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.bootstrap.DefaultComponents] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) using session provider implementation: org.jboss.errai.bus.server.HttpSessionProvider
05:06:48,981 INFO  [org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.bootstrap.LoadExtensions] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) searching for errai extensions ...
05:06:48,988 INFO  [org.jboss.errai.bus.server.service.bootstrap.OrderedBootstrap] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) errai bus started.
05:06:48,992 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 87) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/business-central' for server 'default-server'
05:06:49,436 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 45) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "business-central.war" (runtime-name : "business-central.war")
05:06:50,102 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
05:06:50,105 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 23.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 15.0.1.Final) started in 63177ms - Started 777 of 977 services (349 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
05:06:50,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
05:06:50,106 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
05:06:51,035 INFO  [org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher] (Thread-100) Completed indexing 1 events for indexer [id=org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.CoreIndexer] in cluster [KClusterImpl [clusterId=dashbuilder/datasets/master]].
05:06:51,479 INFO  [org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher] (Thread-101) Completed indexing 1 events for indexer [id=org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.CoreIndexer] in cluster [KClusterImpl [clusterId=dashbuilder/datasets/master]].
05:06:52,300 INFO  [org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher] (Thread-114) Completed indexing 1 events for indexer [id=org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.CoreIndexer] in cluster [KClusterImpl [clusterId=dashbuilder/datasets/master]].
05:06:52,791 INFO  [org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher] (Thread-104) Completed indexing 1 events for indexer [id=org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.CoreIndexer] in cluster [KClusterImpl [clusterId=dashbuilder/datasets/master]].
05:06:52,918 INFO  [org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.util.ServiceUtil] (pool-18-thread-1) Getting reference to managed bean: WildflyDataSourceProvider
05:06:52,930 INFO  [org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.util.ServiceUtil] (pool-18-thread-1) Getting reference to managed bean: WildflyDriverProvider
05:06:53,072 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (pool-18-thread-1) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
05:06:53,336 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (pool-18-thread-1) JBoss Remoting version 5.0.20.Final
05:06:53,503 INFO  [org.xnio] (pool-18-thread-1) XNIO version 3.8.4.Final
05:06:53,511 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (pool-18-thread-1) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.8.4.Final
05:06:53,725 INFO  [org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher] (Thread-116) Completed indexing 1 events for indexer [id=org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.CoreIndexer] in cluster [KClusterImpl [clusterId=dashbuilder/datasets/master]].
05:06:59,428 INFO  [org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher] (Thread-96) Completed indexing 1 events for indexer [id=org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.CoreIndexer] in cluster [KClusterImpl [clusterId=dashbuilder/datasets/master]].
05:07:00,570 INFO  [org.kie.workbench.common.screens.datasource.management.backend.DataSourceManagementBootstrap] (pool-18-thread-1) Initialize deployments task finished successfully.
05:07:00,899 INFO  [org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher] (Thread-105) Completed indexing 1 events for indexer [id=org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.CoreIndexer] in cluster [KClusterImpl [clusterId=dashbuilder/datasets/master]].
05:07:01,820 INFO  [org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.IndexerDispatcher] (Thread-106) Completed indexing 1 events for indexer [id=org.uberfire.ext.metadata.io.CoreIndexer] in cluster [KClusterImpl [clusterId=dashbuilder/datasets/master]].

